# Have the vertical scroll bar always present css

Tags: javascript, css

I have a web page with infinite scrolling.  I always want to have the vertical scrollbar present so I have added the following style:

```
html {  
  overflow-y: scroll;   
}
```

This works in that it shows the scrollbar but it just displays an empty scrollbar, i.e. there is no cursor to allow the user to scroll up or down.

Is it possible to not only display the scrollbar but also have the cursor displaying as well?

Comment: If the content doesn't scroll then the scroll bar will be empty. :P

Comment: What do you mean by "infinite scrolling"? You have content that never ends? Normally, the cursor (I assume you mean the slider element that indicates where you are currently located within the element) will appear as soon as some of the content has overflowed the element on the specified axis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make the html a bit higher and the scroll will show up

```
html {
   overflow-y: scroll;
   height: 101%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to say with the limited information you've provided. What javascript/plugin are you using to achieve infinite scrolling?

My gut instinct is that the infinite scroll may be happening in an element below the top-level html element. Maybe try using your browser's developer's tools to identify which element is actually scrolling, and applying the "overflow-y: scroll;" to that.

Be warned, you may find that the reason they hide the vertical scroll-bar is that the plugin you're using makes it meaningless. If the system deletes old elements from the top of the page so as to not run out of memory, scrolling to the top of the scroll-bar may not take you to the top of the page.

Comment: It is my own javascript and not a plug in.  The code allows the user to scroll dates from the past or the present.  The problem is that in some instances there is not much data when the user first loads the page so the scroll bar is empty and they cannot scroll forward in time or backwards in time.

Comment: I see, did Zoltan Toth's solution above work? If so, use it. Otherwise, I'd suggest doing a check upon page load to see if there is enough data and, if there isn't, loading the next set automatically until you do have enough data to fill the page.

Comment: Zoltan's solution was the answer.